# How to fix 'Imported file has a wrong encoding: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 21221: character maps to' error?

Tags: django, csv, import

I'm trying to import a csv file to my django project. Until now, the previous times I did this i never had a problem. However, all of a sudden I keep getting this error that says "Imported file has a wrong encoding: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 21221: character maps to" when i try to import the csv file in.

I don't understand why I am getting the error

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

this is what i keep getting.

I am trying to import my excel file like this:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

and this is what my csv file looks like:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

\

Comment: Your post is not complete. You never had this problem may be because the CSV file you previously imported did not have weird characters. you will face this issue on CSV files with strange characters. to fix it you could upgrade to `django-import-export==3.0.0b4` if you are using this as your import tool. you could use also `f= open("my_file.csv", encoding="utf8")` in your python code importing the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Hex character 9d is not a printable character (https://www.codetable.net/hex/9d). In unicode it appears to be some kind of command. You will need to sanitise this character to be able to handle it in a csv file.

Edit: As @snakecharmerb points out in the comments, there are encodings where this is a valid character. However, I suspect from your question that you are not using one of these.

You can also look into `decode` to allow you to specify a charset for reading the data. If you have a charset that you think this is a valid char for, then perhaps your routine is picking up a different default charset from the system.

I actually do something like this to make sure I get Swedish chars properly set. This is directly from my code when extracting fields

```
output.decode('iso-8859-1').strip()
```

Comment: This is not true. 0x9d is a valid character in a number of 8-bit encodings - see https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#9d

Comment: You're quite right of course, there are different encodings, though I think if the OP was using one of those they wouldn't get the error they are getting. It's entirely possible the default encoding of the systems the file is created on then read on is different, and the subsequent translation is causing the issue. I've added a comment about using decode.

Answer (score 0):

The csv file contains invalid data for the encoding that you are attempting to interpret it with. Depending on how it was generated, you might be able to tell Python what is the correct decoding to apply when you open it

```
f = open(csv_file_name, encoding= ...)
```

or you might specify an appropriate encoding when you generate the csv file, or you might be processing dodgy data and have to resort to `encoding="latin-1"` -- which may result in putting bad data in to your database, if you don't validate what comes out of the csv file through a Django form before saving it.

I'd recommend always processing rows of csv data through Django forms or modelforms. It makes it very easy to catch errors (form is not valid, form.errors, etc. ) and print out useful error messages about what is wrong with which field (column) of the row.

Lots more [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)